# Adwords Keyword Report returning different data in individual queries than combined query

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

We are querying the Adwords API to retrieve data for keywords. When querying individual days we get other data then when querying all days combined in a single query.

We are querying the `KEYWORDS_PERFORMANE_REPORT`

```
campaign = AdwordsCampaign.find 957

# Weirdness returning from the Adwords keyword performance report
campaign.adwords.keyword_performance({min: Date.parse("2014-05-18"), max: Date.parse("2014-05-18")}).map{|kw| kw[:conversions]}.inject(:+)
#=> 0
campaign.adwords.keyword_performance({min: Date.parse("2014-05-19"), max: Date.parse("2014-05-19")}).map{|kw| kw[:conversions]}.inject(:+)
#=> 2
campaign.adwords.keyword_performance({min: Date.parse("2014-05-20"), max: Date.parse("2014-05-20")}).map{|kw| kw[:conversions]}.inject(:+)
#=> 0
campaign.adwords.keyword_performance({min: Date.parse("2014-05-18"), max: Date.parse("2014-05-20")}).map{|kw| kw[:conversions]}.inject(:+)
#=> 6
#=> waat moment - it should be 2?
```

The code for querying retrieving the results is here: https://gist.github.com/1f97a174ee6dd8ae51ea

Does someone have an idea what is going on/what we are doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be because you are querying on _today's_ data? maybe the data has changed since the previous query? does it happen in date ranges that do not include today?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an inconsistency in the AdWords API -- You are simply counting the same two conversions three times in your `keyword_performance` method.  Here's why:

### Global Keyword Id

A keyword has [one Id globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111884/are-adwords-keyword-adgroup-campaign-ids-unique-across-multiple-accounts) -- across all of AdWords -- that represents a unique combination of `KeywordText` and `MatchType`.  A keyword can appear in multiple ad groups within a campaign.  For example, if you have a phrase match keyword "cat videos" in two different ad groups in the same campaign, the keyword's Id will be the same in both places.

In your gist, you call the AdWords API twice.  The first time, you ask for the number of conversions per unique keyword `Id`, regardless of `AdGroupId`.  This will return only one row for the "cat videos" phrase match keyword (per`ConversionCategoryName`), and will include all conversions of that type that this keyword got anywhere in the campaign.

In the second API call, you ask for several fields, including `AdGroupId`.  Inclusion of the `AdGroupId` field causes the report to be [segmented](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting-concepts#segmentation) by ad group.  So if a keyword appears in multiple ad groups, then you will get a separate row for each one.

By assigning the **total** number of conversions to **each** of these rows, you end up counting the same conversions multiple times.

### Why does this only happen over the larger date range?

This is because you are excluding zero-impression rows.  The longer the date range, the more likely that keywords appearing in more than one ad group have had at least one impression in multiple ad groups, and will therefore have multiple rows in your second report.

#### An Example:

Let's say that you have the following AdGroup-Keyword combinations in your campaign:

- AG1-KW1
- AG1-KW2
- AG2-KW1
- AG2-KW3
- AG3-KW1
- AG3-KW4
- AG4-KW2

5/18 -- KW1 gets no conversions, but gets at least one impression in each of the AdGroups where it appears.

5/19 -- KW1 again gets no conversions.

5/20 -- AG1-KW1 gets 2 conversions.  AG2-KW1 and AG3-KW1 get zero impressions.

If you pull a report for just 5/20, only AG1-KW1 will have a row in your second report, while AG2-KW1 and AG3-KW1 will be excluded.  KW1's conversions will be counted once.

But over the course of 5/18-5/20, AG1-KW1, AG2-KW1, and AG3-KW1 each have at least one impression.  If you pull a report for this date range, then each of the three will have a row in your second report.  KW1's conversions will be counted three times.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. I tried removing those columns you mentioned. So I am only querying `['KeywordText', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Ctr', 'Conversions', 'Cost', 'Id']` - however I get the same results. Am I missing a segment?

Comment: Can you post an updated Gist?  In general, I'd suggest breaking your code into smaller methods so that you can look at intermediate output -- the parsed CSVs, for example, before additional processing.  This way you can see where individual conversions are coming from, and which rows are included in which report.  There is also the question of whether you WANT to measure keyword performance simply across the whole campaign, or by ad group.  Personally, I might just segment BOTH reports by ad group and use something like "#{ad_group_id}-#{keyword_id}" as the hash key for conversions.